# Can you turn a zip file containing HTML, JS and 50 or so PNGs into a working EXE file?

Tags: javascript, html, zip, png, exe

I'm making a geoguessr like game with html js and some png files but I want it to be an exe file, is it possible to add the code files and the images into a zip file then turn it into a exe that works? if so, how?

Comment: While it is probably possible to do this, maybe you'd be interested in HTML Applications? Check out the .hta file extension if so!

Comment: or look into `nwjs` if you don't want to restrict yourself to Microsoft Windows